# Virtual hosting

Tags: apache2, mod-rewrite

I want to use domains like xxx.abc.domain.tld.
The xxx is my folder to access. I tried it with the rewrite rules, but I can't get it working, because I don't know how to get the part xxx from the SERVER_NAME into my RewriteRule.

This was my try:

```
UseCanonicalName Off

# include the IP address in the logs so they may be split
LogFormat "%A %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vaccess.log vcommon

RewriteEngine On

# a ServerName derived from a Host: header may be any case at all
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

## deal with normal documents first:
# do the magic
RewriteCond ${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}} ^.+\.abc\.domain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/abc.domain.tld/[xxx-part]/$1 [L]
```

Perhaps there is a better solution.
In generally I want to create a dynamic login system with mod_auth_mysql and for each xxx is a seperate user database.
I would prefer the domain/address syntax abc.domain.tld/xxx, but I don't know how to realize it.

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 3):

Would it not be easier to inject the hostname into the rewrite rule via a RewriteCond back-reference?

```
UseCanonicalName Off

# include the IP address in the logs so they may be split
LogFormat "%A %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vaccess.log vcommon

RewriteEngine On

# a ServerName derived from a Host: header may be any case at all
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

## deal with normal documents first:
# do the magic
RewriteCond ${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}} ^(.+)\.abc\.domain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/abc.domain.tld/%1/$1 [L]
```

See [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation, under RewriteRule "back-references." Notice the use of the `%1` instead of the `$1` backreference. This should grab the contents of the regular expression sub-match in the RewriteCond above. I have added parenthesis to submatch the 'xxx' portion in the RewriteCond.

Comment: I want to use the 'xxx' portion to determine which system shall be loaded. Is there any possibility to let run a mysql basic auth with svn and trac? Because I don't know how to replace the `<Location /svn>` with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Now I'm really confused ... You spoke of xxx -> folder in your question. Maybe you should edit the question and be more specific about everything you're trying to accomplish. Url is broken up as scheme://hostname:port/path?query. mod_rewrite can only be used to manipulate everything after the hostname:port.  I can't think of any way to create a single virtual host configuration which covers so many varied hosts and still provides a configuration for Auth, SVN, Trac etc.  In short, you're trying to accomplish too many things at once.

Comment: There were two ideas for the url, xxx.abc.domain.tld and abc.domain.tld/xxx. I choiced now for abc.domain.tld/xxx because I need only two hosting settings, with the rewriterule adapted from yours I wrote a new rule, which match my url, but how can I pass a environmental variable to AuthMySQL_DB?

Comment: ... but how can I pass a the 'xxx' part as database to AuthMySQL_DB svn_[xxx part]_ and as part of the svn repo SVNPath /var/svn/[xxx part]?

Comment: To avoid more confusion, I mark this question as solved, because your answer has solved the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the URLs that are being used contain the xxx as part of the server name then it's possible to use [Name Based virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) e.g.

If you have `xxx.abc.domain.tld` and `yyy.abc.domain.tld` then you could setup a virtual host for each e.g.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxx.abc.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/abc.domain.tld/xxx
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yyy.abc.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/abc.domain.tld/yyy
</VirtualHost>
```

and so on.

If you want to use abc.domain.tld/xxx, abc.domain.com.tld/yyy etc. then just set up a single host, define the DocumentRoot and the /xxx, /yyy etc would just be directories under DocumentRoot.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/abc.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, abc.domain.tld/xxx would be directed to /var/www/abc.domain.tld/xxx and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That is the system I used before, but hosting and managing a lot of subdomains is very circular. There is one domain with a lot of subdomains containing two locations. One of the location use the mod_wsgi and the other mod_dav_svn. It should be dynamically.